# Webgl shader attrib type not matched

Tags: webgl2, geometry-instancing, twgl.js

I have a buffer like this use it in instancing of a curve geometry 

`Distance: {
    numComponents: 1,
    data: new Uint8Array(0),
    type: gl.BYTE , // signed byte
    normalize: true,
    divisor: 1
}`

vertex shader is:

```
#version 300 es

precision highp float;
precision highp int;

in  vec2 Pos;
in  vec2 Center;
in  mat2 Rotate;
in  float Length;
in  float Size;
in  float Distance;

uniform float zoom;
uniform vec2 scale;
uniform float ratio;
uniform vec2 resolution;
uniform vec2 move;

void main() {        
    // setting the gl_Position
}
```

and Fragment shader is:

```
#version 300 es

precision highp float;
precision highp int;

out vec4 FragColor;

void main() {
    FragColor = vec4( 1.0 , vec2(0.0), 1.0 ) ;
}
```

when I run the code it give me no error but just one warning which is

`[.Offscreen-For-WebGL-00000200FD87E610]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawArraysIntancedANGLE: vertexAttrib function must match shader attrib type`

can any body help me what am I do wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to post more code. Like your shader, how is your `Distance` attribute declared in the shader?

Comment: and I will update data of Distance after using `twgl.setAttribInfoBufferFromArray`

Comment: @gman ,Ok Thanks for your attention. I had add my glsls. thanks for helping

Comment: I had use a wrong program info in VAO